How to render an icon with text in a table cell using react and typescript?
i am new to react programming and typescript. i am currently tying to add an icon with text in a react table cell.
below is what i am trying to achieve.

as seen from above i want to render the second column with icon and text.
these text1, not-applicable and text2 values are in variable named output got from backend.

now when output is "text2" we display text2 without any icon
when output is "text1" and boolean variable named isAvailable is true we show triangle icon with text1
when output is "text1" and boolean variable named isAvaiable is false we show oval icon with text1
when output is "not-applicable" we show rectangle icon

below is my code,
return (
    <>
      {output === 'not-applicable' && 
          <>
              <Icon
                  name='square' color='gray'
              />
              <span>{output}</span>
           </>
      }
      {(isAvailable && output === 'text1') && 
          <>
              <Icon
                  name='triangle' color='blue'
              />
              <span>{output}</span>
          </>
      }
      {(!isAvailable && output === 'text1') && 
          <>
              <Icon
                  name='triangle' color='orange'
              />
              <span>{output}</span>
          </>
      }
      {output === 'text2' && <span>{output}</span>}
    </>
);

the above code works.
but i want to have a cleaner solution. here i am repeating code. is there a way to rewrite this better. thanks.

Kudos for noticing a suboptimal pattern that could be bettered. I think you could create an external function that takes care of that extra logic and returns a single output. It's also much better to just add an attribute to the DB (or whatever is storing the data in the backend) that specifies the output but if that's a viable option for your exercises.

The returned JSX is very repetitive.  In order to make it cleaner, I would separate the JSX part from the conditional logic that determines which, if any, icon to display.
function getIcon(output: string, isAvailable: boolean): string | undefined {
    if (output === 'not-applicable') {
        return 'square';
    }
    if (output === 'text1') {
        return isAvailable ? 'triangle' : 'oval';
    }
    return;
}

function renderCell(output: string, isAvailable: boolean) {
    const icon = getIcon(output, isAvailable);
    return (
        <>
            {icon && <Icon name={icon} />}
            <span>{output}</span>
        </>
    );
}


Here's another slightly different way to write the same thing. Maybe getIcon doesn't need to be a function, and we can just define the icon name as variable directly.
function renderCell(output: string, isAvailable: boolean) {
    let icon: string | undefined = undefined;

    if (output === 'not-applicable') {
        icon = 'square';
    } else if (output === 'text1') {
        icon = isAvailable ? 'triangle' : 'oval';
    }

    return (
        <>
            {icon && <Icon name={icon} />}
            <span>{output}</span>
        </>
    );
}


thanks for the answer. there is also color which i added as typo in my question. edited it now.

@Harika in that case I would probably change it so that icon is an object with name and color properties.  If it's a 1-to-1 mapping of icon names to colors (ie. all triangles are always blue) then I would store that relationship as a dictionary object, keep the code the same as my answer, and handle the color in the Icon component.
